# Wix how to disable minor upgrade

Tags: svn, wix, windows-installer, installation

Currently we are using wix to create installer for our project. We've already implemented  for the project ( we specified  since we're automating the build process and don't want developers to have to change it manually every time )

However, we're binding the SVN revision to the 4th number in version ( like this : [ 1.0.0.SVNRevision ] so every SVN build create a minor upgrade that cause various problem to our installation

So, do we have a way to manage those minor upgrade without messing with the already implemented major upgrade? some way to just disable the installation if it is a minor upgrade would be simple and nice
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate that MSI ignores the 4th field of ProductVersion. But there's several ways to address this problem.

1)  Change your version strategy so that every build has a change in the first three.  1.0.1  1.0.2 1.0.3 and so on.

2) Use the detect same version attribute on the MajorUpgrade element.

3) Write a simple custom action to augment FindRelatedProducts that queries the MSI API to find products that match your ProductVersion or higher and put the ProductCode into the action property so that RemoveExistingProducts can remove it.

Comment: Thanks.
We can not change the version naming convention but i think Custom Action would be able to help